# Ejabberd MQTT on AWS fails to launch: undefined exit with reason {'EXIT',{undef,[{mod_mqtt,socket_type,[],[]}

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, ejabberd, tls1.2

I follow the tutorial https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/mqtt/#enabling-mqtt-service-in-ejabberd.

Here is my config, the same as tutorial. And I also open port 1883, 8883 on AWS security group.

```
hosts:
  - "localhost"

listen:
  -
    port: 1883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000      
  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
       ...
       "/mqtt": mod_mqtt
  -
    port: 8883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
    tls: true

# adapt the path to your own certfile    
certfiles:
  - "/var/snap/ejabberd/tls/mqtt.pem"

modules:
...
  mod_mqtt: {}
```

However ejabberd fails to launch, throwing the errors below:

```
2020-03-29 21:30:59.416 [error] <0.299.0> Supervisor ejabberd_listener had child 
{1883,{0,0,0,0},tcp} started with ejabberd_listener:start({1883,{0,0,0,0},tcp}, 
mod_mqtt, [{backlog,1000}]) at undefined exit with reason {'EXIT',{undef,
[{mod_mqtt,socket_type,[],[]},{ejabberd_listener,start,3,[{file,
"src/ejabberd_listener.erl"},{line,86}]},{supervisor,do_start_child,2,[{file,
"supervisor.erl"},{line,358}]},{supervisor,start_children,3,[{file,
"supervisor.erl"},{line,341}]},{supervisor,init_children,2,[{file,
"supervisor.erl"},{line,307}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},
{line,328}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}} 
in context start_error
```

and

```
2020-03-29 21:29:31.371 [error] <0.38.0>@ejabberd_config:validate_opts:1022 
unknown option 'certfiles' will be likely ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {undef, [{mod_mqtt,socket_type,[],[]},

This means that erlang couldn't find the file `mod_mqtt.beam`... or maybe the file was found, but it didn't include the definition of the function socket_type/0. That module with that function was added in ejabberd 19.02: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/a3df791373c30ccc79a6082f4c910a378d726cdc

So, maybe you installed an older version, or it is wrongly installed and lacks that module.

> unknown option 'certfiles' will be likely ignored

The option `certfiles` was adde in ejabberd 17.11, so I don't understand how a recent ejabberd can complain that it is unknown:

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/35b7203e01aefbdfe4ea7804ebe20a8667466628

Comment: I just found my package from Snap Store is 17.07! Feels like the version on snap store and apt-get is not actively maintained. I try a new version 20.03, it works. Thank you !!